# Puppet agent runs more often than runinterval

Tags: puppet

I have a puppet agent and master on separate servers.  On the agent, I have

```
runinterval=5m
```

in both the main and agent sections.  However, in the log (/var/log/messages) I see this:

```
Jun 13 13:16:30 devserver puppet-agent[11969]: testjunk
Jun 13 13:16:30 devserver puppet-agent[11969]: (/Stage[main]//Notify[testjunk]/message) defined 'message' as 'testjunk'
Jun 13 13:16:31 devserver puppet-agent[11969]: Finished catalog run in 1.82 seconds
Jun 13 13:16:38 devserver puppet-agent[11969]: testjunk
Jun 13 13:16:38 devserver puppet-agent[11969]: (/Stage[main]//Notify[testjunk]/message) defined 'message' as 'testjunk'
Jun 13 13:16:38 devserver puppet-agent[11969]: Finished catalog run in 1.82 seconds
Jun 13 13:16:46 devserver puppet-agent[11969]: testjunk
Jun 13 13:16:46 devserver puppet-agent[11969]: (/Stage[main]//Notify[testjunk]/message) defined 'message' as 'testjunk'
Jun 13 13:16:46 devserver puppet-agent[11969]: Finished catalog run in 1.83 seconds
```

It's waking up and running every few seconds.  Any idea what could be going on here?

Comment: Does restarting the agent do anything? What is the output of `puppet agent --configprint runinterval`?

Comment: I have restarted it many times. No effect. 
$ puppet agent --configprint runinterval
5m